# Running command after server started - Docker, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

Tags: docker, scrapy, dockerfile, scrapyd

So, I have a `Dockerfile` where I want to keep my `scrapyd` server. But, since I am using `scrapyd-deploy` to deploy my `Scrapy` project, I need to wait for the `scrapyd` server to run before deploying the eggs. I am not sure how to accomplish that with `Docker` since if I use `scrapyd` as the entrypoint, it "steals" the terminal and I am not able to run the `scrapyd-deploy` in sequence.

For now, I have something that works, but this looks really, really "hacky" for me and I don't like it. What would be the correct way to do it?

```
FROM python:3.6
SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]

# here comes a lot of configuration, copying files, installing stuff, etc ...

# important part that I think is hacky comes at the end:
# the command below redirect scrapyd streams to /dev/null, send it to the background, deploy the eggs, than run a dummy command to keep the container alive
CMD scrapyd >& /dev/null & cd ali && scrapyd-deploy && tail -f /dev/null
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I knew it should not be that complicated to manage process with Linux. #loveLinux #linuxRocks

So, I found a way to get the `scrapyd` server process to the background, do my deployment with `scrapyd-deploy` and then get the server back to the foreground again to avoid `Docker` killing my container. That's the `CMD` line that solves it all (with comments):

```
# Set bash monitor mode on; run server on the background, deploy eggs, get server to the foreground again.
CMD set -m; scrapyd & cd ali && scrapyd-deploy && fg scrapyd
```